# Existing react app compiles but does not render with webpack dev server

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I set up webpack for my existing react app. This is my first time using webpack. The dev server compiles with no warinings or error, but nothing renders in the dom. I think it has something to do with my HtmlWebpackPlugin setup (or my index.html). All the files needed for the setup are in this code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-babel-app-vo6lv7?file=/src/App.js). My webpack config is in the "config" directory. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding react fast refresh plugin. Make sure to add it to babel config js (https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin).

Comment: Consider also mark the answer as ***Accepted*** to notify others that the question has been solved.